# Formatting C code for a document

Tags: c, documentation, ms-word

I am working on a book containing a number of C examples.  I am looking for a way I can spit the code through a processor that will give it to me with alternating grey/white lines with line numbers and b&w only syntax highlighting.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Alan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you want to use MS-Word, especially for a book text? If it's not completely required, have a look at latex and packages like:

- [listings](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/)
- [minted](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/minted)

Alternatively if you don't want to do full, proper text layout, just find some application which does format the code and copy&paste it. Visual Studio can copy formats apparently.

Comment: [texments](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/texments/) is similar to minted

Comment: Looked at Lyx ( http://www.lyx.org ) which is a visual front end because I didn't want all of latex to "get in the way".  The code looks great, and I *think* it will be worth all of the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Download [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download) then select

```
TextFX -> TextFX Edit -> Reindent C++ code|Indent & surround| ...| more options
```

To get the colors read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719667/notepad-highlight-colours)

Then just paste it in your word processor.